# Unable to make multi-line rsyslog statements filter incoming syslogs to different files

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have tried this so many different ways. I have a incoming syslog feed to port 1522 from a proxy server. I am trying to match a part of the message/body "location=" and send each log from a certain location to its own file. I have done this on a small scale, but never a long multiline.

**Sample syslog:**

```
Feb 22 22:59:51 192.168.0.126 |2019-02-22 22:58:20|reason=Allowed|event_id=6660962988918112262|protocol=HTTP|action=Allowed|transactionsize=8374|responsesize=6073|requestsize=2301|urlcategory=Internet Services|serverip=52.114.76.34|clienttranstime=125000|requestmethod=CONNECT|refererURL=None|useragent=Unknown|product=NSS|location=ABC Corporation|ClientIP=192.168.1.152|status=200|user=ABC Corporation|url=mobile.pipe.aria.microsoft.com|vendor=Zscaler|hostname=mobile.pipe.aria.microsoft.com|clientpublicIP=192.65.41.5|threatcategory=Clean Transaction|threatname=None|filetype=None|appname=Common Office 365 Applications|pagerisk=0|department=Default Department|urlsupercategory=Internet Communication|appclass=Business|dlpengine=None|urlclass=Business Use|threatclass=Clean Transaction|dlpdictionaries=None|fileclass=None|bwthrottle=NO|servertranstime=125000
```

I have tried the below variations in my /etc/rsyslog.d/networks.conf file, but none are matching location and directing to different files:

**TAKE-1:**

```
template(name="abc-zscaler-web" type="string" string="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/abc-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
template(name="def-zscaler-web" type="string" string="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/def-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
template(name="ghi-zscaler-web" type="string" string="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/ghi-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
$RuleSet Remote1522
$RuleSet CreateMainQueue on
if $msg contains 'location=ABC ' then {action(type="omfile" DynaFile="abc-zscaler-web") stop}
if $msg contains 'location=DEF ' then {action(type="omfile" DynaFile="def-zscaler-web") stop}
if $msg contains 'location=GHI ' then {action(type="omfile" DynaFile="ghi-zscaler-web") stop}
*.* then {action(type="omfile" DynaFile="abc-zscaler-web") stop}
$InputTCPServerBindRuleset Remote1522
$InputTCPServerRun 1522
```

**TAKE-2:**

```
$RuleSet Remote1522
$RuleSet CreateMainQueue on
if $msg contains "location=ABC " then /var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/abc-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log
if $msg contains "location=ABC " then stop
if $msg contains "location=DEF " then /var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/def-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log
if $msg contains "location=DEF " then stop
if $msg contains "location=GHI " then /var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/ghi-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log
if $msg contains "location=GHI " then stop
*.* /var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/abc-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log
$InputTCPServerBindRuleset Remote1522
$InputTCPServerRun 1522
```

**TAKE-3**

```
$RuleSet Remote1522
$RuleSet CreateMainQueue on
if ( $msg contains 'location=ABC ') then {
               action(type="omfile" file="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/abc-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
}      else if ($msg contains 'location=DEF ') then {
               action(type="omfile" file="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/def-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
}      else if ($msg contains 'location=GHI ') then {
               action(type="omfile" file="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/ghi-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
}      else {action(type="omfile" file="/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/abc-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log")
}
$InputTCPServerBindRuleset Remote1522
$InputTCPServerRun 1522
```

**TAKE-4 (*there are more, but this is the last meaningful*)**

```
$template abc-zscaler-web,"/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/abc-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log"
$template def-zscaler-web,"/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/def-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log"
$template ghi-zscaler-web,"/var/rsyslog/zscaler-web/%FROMHOST%/ghi-%$year%-%$month%-%$day%.log"
$RuleSet Remote1522
$RuleSet CreateMainQueue on
if $msg contains 'location=ABC ' then -?abc-zscaler-web
if $msg contains 'location=ABC ' then stop
if $msg contains 'location=DEF ' then -?def-zscaler-web
if $msg contains 'location=DEF ' then stop
if $msg contains 'location=GHI ' then -?ghi-zscaler-web
if $msg contains 'location=GHI ' then stop
*.*  -?abc-zscaler-web
$InputTCPServerBindRuleset Remote1522
$InputTCPServerRun 1522
```

Am I missing something in my reiner scripts. The code/locations were sanitized to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is simply an error in your copy here, but the line

```
$RuleSet CreateMainQueue on
```

should be

```
$RuleSetCreateMainQueue on
```

If you were to test the syntax of your server configuration file with something like `rsyslogd -N1 -f server.conf` you would have seen the error:

```
rsyslogd: error: extra characters in config line ignored: 'on'
```

The end result is that you define a ruleset called *CreateMainQueue* instead of *Remote1522*.